# Compilation error Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line

Tags: kotlin

My Code

```
public fun main() {

  var celsius:Double = 30.0
  var farenheight:Double = (celsius * 9)/5) + 32

  println("$farenheight degrees farenheight = $celsius degrees celsius")

//var farenheight:Double = 86.0
//var celsius:Double = (farenheight - 32) * 5/9

//println("$celsius degrees celsius = $farenheight degrees farenheight")


}
```

Error im getting is Unexpected tokens (use ';' to separate expressions on the same line)

Answer (score 2):

You opened only a single parenthesis, but closed two of them:

```kotlin
(celsius * 9)/5)
```

Just remove the second one:

```kotlin
var farenheight:Double = (celsius * 9)/5 + 32
```

Actually, you don't need any parentheses at all, as the order of operations will be the same:

```kotlin
var farenheight:Double = celsius * 9 / 5 + 32
```